# AS3 Air app setinterval not pausing when not in focus

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I have an air app for iOS that plays a continuous sound to the user and there are settings to allow the app to periodically vibrate if audio is playing (notify the user if their volume is down basically). The app is able to continue playing the audio in the background however the timer event which is just a simple setinterval doesn't continue or pause.

So for example, the user will start play back, 10 seconds the device will vibrate, 10 seconds later another vibrate etc. If the user puts the app into the background (goes to their home screen etc) the audio continues which is great, but then in say 30 seconds they return to my app, the device will vibrate 3 times as it seems to store the amount of intervals have passed.

I guess my questions are:
- Can I have the app vibrate while in the background too?
- Can I have the app pause the interval when app loses focus and resume when it gets focus back?

If neither of the above are possible I will just have to exit on suspend.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pause the setInterval on Deactivate and resume it on ACTIVATE, for that you have to add two event listeners. And you can code for your setinterval in that section accordingly.

Event Listeners :

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, appActivateHandler);
stage.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, appDeactivateHandler);
```

in deactivate listener you have to set :

```
stage.focus = null;
```

try it, this can help you.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't end up using in the end. Just 'exit on suspend' instead.